# VBA to save the `.ShowDetail` of a Pivot table to individual workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel project with a list of clients. Each client has a total spent in each year and whenever I click in each year for each client it opens a dinamic table with information regarding that year. Instead of that, I want to export the results into different excel files for each client.

Here's an example:
[image]

I've seen other people with the same issue but still can't understand what's wrong. I don't have experience with VBA and I'm helping a friend, so maybe it's something basic that I don't know of.
The error has to do with the ShowDetail and cells, it might not be able to capture what's in the loop.

```
 Sub Reports()

    Dim i As Double
    Dim Ini As Double
    Dim Fin As Double

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("MainTable").Select
    With Sheets("MainTable")

    Ini = Columns(1).Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
    Fin = .PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Name").VisibleItems.Count

    For i = 1 To Fin

            .Cells(i + Ini, 2).ShowDetail = True

            Sheets(1).Name = .Cells(i + Ini, 1).Value

        ActiveSheet.Select

        ActiveSheet.Move

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name

                    ActiveWorkbook.Close False

                        Next i

            End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub
```

I want this to export the results into different excel files for each client.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

- First one was the wrong reference to the cell whose value is set to `.ShowDetails`
- Then it would be renaming `Sheet(1)` every time in the loop.

**Code:**

```
Sub Reports()

    Dim i As Double
    Dim Ini As Double
    Dim Fin As Double
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

With Sheets("MainTable")

    Ini = .Columns(1).Range("A2").End(xlDown).row
    Fin = .PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Name").VisibleItems.Count

    For i = 1 To Fin

            .Cells(i + Ini - Fin - 1, 2).ShowDetail = True

            ActiveSheet.Name = .Cells(i + Ini - Fin - 1, 1).Value & .Cells(Ini - Fin - 1, 2).Value
            ActiveSheet.Move
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name
            ActiveWorkbook.Close False

     Next i

End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Code will work on Pivot which starts from `A2` and looks similar to

[image]

You can create another loop for other years. For sample I created this short Pivot.

Comment: How do I do it?

Comment: Include another loop, Change the Column number from 2 to 3. i.e change `.Cells(i + Ini - Fin - 1, 2)` to `.Cells(i + Ini - Fin - 1, 3)`

Comment: It works perfectly except for some clients with long names (I believe there is a maximum of 31 characters in the name). I'll see how to fix that.

Comment: I added Left(.Cells(i + Ini - Fin - 1, 1).Value, 26) so that it doesn't exceed the characters. Thanks again! First time I was using this.

Comment: Great ... All the Best :)